# What scripts are available for fixing up styling bugs & shortcomings in IE?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, css-selectors, polyfills

There are several helpful JavaScripts and .htc behaviors that patch over the holes & buggy features in Internet Explorer's rendering engine. It seems most of them have some overlapping or incomplete feature support and it's hard to decide what to use:

- [DD_Roundies](http://dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/): border-radius
- [Fetchak ie-css3](http://www.fetchak.com/ie-css3/): border-radius, box-shadow, text-shadow emulation using VML
- [Keith Clark's ie-css3](http://www.keithclark.co.uk/labs/ie-css3/): advanced selector support
- [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/): border-radius, box-shadow, border-image, multiple background images, linear-gradient as background image, rgba
- [IE PNG Fix](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/): Alpha-transparent PNG support using AlphaImageLoader
- [DD Belated PNG Fix](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/): Alpha-transparent PNG support using VML
- [Dean Edwards IE[7-9].js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/): advanced selectors, alpha-transparent PNG, position:fixed, min/max-width/height, box-sizing
- [eCSStender](http://ecsstender.org/): css3 selectors
- [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/): css3 selectors

*Please add to this list if you have any more: this is a community wiki.*

Which are your preferred scripts? What are the benefits & limitations & gotchas?

Update: these scripts are now commonly called "Polyfills"

Comment: My favorite is a script which displays the following message to the user: "Download Firefox." ;)

Answer (score 2):

Not a script, but probably worth mentioning the [Google Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/) plug-in:

> Google Chrome Frame is an open source plug-in that seamlessly brings Google Chrome's open web technologies and speedy JavaScript engine to Internet Explorer. With Google Chrome Frame, you can:
>
> - Start using open web technologies - like the HTML5 canvas tag - right away, even technologies that aren't yet supported in Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8.
> - Take advantage of JavaScript performance improvements to make your apps faster and more responsive.

Answer (score 1):

[HTML5 Shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/): HTML5 IE enabling script.

But basically, these scripts get the work done, but at the cost of performance issues and such. There are some acceptable workarounds such as [using "PNG8 alpha transparency" as a replacement for PNG fix](http://www.ethanandjamie.com/blog/81-png8-transparency-without-fireworks). It's just a matter of project type.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest also Blueprint CSS

http://www.blueprintcss.org/

Quoting their website..

> What does Blueprint have to offer?
>
> ```
> * A CSS reset that eliminates the discrepancies across browsers.
> * A solid grid that can support the most complex of layouts.
> * Typography based on expert principles that predate the web.
> * Form styles for great looking user interfaces.
> * Print styles for making any webpage ready for paper.
> * Plugins for buttons, tabs and sprites.
> * Tools, editors, and templates for every step in your workflow.
> ```

Comment: This is not a polyfill. It does include a "reset" stylesheet, but it doesn't address any features missing from IE.